# NuGet Client SDK - Connecting to a private NuGet feed through code

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I'm using a private NuGet feed through Azure DevOps.
To see information about a **public** NuGet package from code, one simply has to follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk#get-package-metadata).
In particular:

```
ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
CancellationToken cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

SourceCacheContext cache = new SourceCacheContext();
SourceRepository repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
PackageMetadataResource resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();

IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> packages = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(
    "Newtonsoft.Json",
    includePrerelease: true,
    includeUnlisted: false,
    cache,
    logger,
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result for my own private feed by adding my credentials to the process:

```
var logger = NullLogger.Instance;
var cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;

var cache = new SourceCacheContext();    
var source = new PackageSource("*my feed*/nuget/v3/index.json");
source.Credentials = new PackageSourceCredential("*my feed*/nuget/v3/index.json", "*username*", "*password*", true, null);

var repository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV2(source);
var resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();

IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> searchMetadata = await resource.GetMetadataAsync(
    "My.Package.Name",
    includePrerelease: true,
    includeUnlisted: false,
    cache,
    logger,
    cancellationToken);
```

Please note, that even though I call the `Factory.GetCoreV2()`, the inside of the method still calls V3 providers. It's simply the only constructor that takes a PackageSource as a parameter:

```
public static SourceRepository GetCoreV2(this Repository.RepositoryFactory factory, PackageSource source)
{
     return Repository.CreateSource(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3(), source);
}
```

However, no matter what I do, I cannot get through step

> `var resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();`

which keeps failing with a `NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException - 401 Unauthorised`. I've verified the validity of my credentials and my feed endpoint, as well as my permissions within the feed (full access). I've also tried the initialisation process described [here](https://daveaglick.com/posts/exploring-the-nuget-v3-libraries-part-2) (plus the step with my credentials), yet the result is the same.

How am I expected to identify to an Azure DevOps feed from code, to be able to get the IPackageMetadata information?

Comment: Did you ever get this working @derptastic ? there seem to be very few samples for nuget SDK using a secure feed like devops

Comment: @Quango Unfortunately not. The effort to get it to work fell outside the scope of the task at the time, and it hasn't been a priority since.

Comment: @derptasic  I found an alternative approach using the DevOps REST API to manage the Nuget feeds, and have been able to delete several hundred old versions of packages that moved to another devops instance. If you're interested i'll put some code up on GitHub

Comment: @Quango Sure - I'd love to see it! Even just for posterity's sake, it might help someone stumbling on this question.

Comment: Done - I added it as a new answer so people can see it. Pretty simple - query the feeds, packages and versions, and also allow Delete Version to clean up.

Comment: Hi @Derptastic,
I have included the same code and added token name and personal access token as username and password. Still, I'm seeing "NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException - 401 Unauthorised".

Please suggest how it got fixed for you.

Comment: Hey @KalyaniReddy, I am no longer in the company, so I cannot provide any code examples, but at face value - using the PAT as a username seems wrong. Try using your regular username and the PAT as a password only. Additionally, my examples are of a code that's *not* working. >JosephPietrzak has posted an example he said that works for him, but I am afraid I cannot be of further help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure DevOps doesn't support username & password authentication through NuGet. If your account needs 2 factor authentication (2FA), there's no way for NuGet to prompt you for it. I don't know if they decided not to support it for all accounts, even ones that are not 2FA enabled, or if there are other reasons as well (I suspect it's not allowed for other security reasons).

If you have Visual Studio installed, or have otherwise installed the [Azure Artifacts NuGet credentials provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider), maybe you could try not using any credentials in your code. I'm not sure how exactly nuget.exe, dotnet cli and msbuild discover the credentials provider, but maybe it works when using the sdk as well.

Otherwise if you want to, or need to, use the credentials API, you need to generate a [personal access token](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider), and use that as the password.

Answer (score 3):

I dug a little deeper and it does seem to be possible, please see this Gist with an example implementation
https://gist.github.com/cpyfferoen/74092a74b165e85aed5ca1d51973b9d2

Comment: This worked perfectly - highly recommend copying the class to Stackoverflow (and removing this line "InitPackageSource")

Answer (score 3):

An alternative route to managing secure DevOps package feeds is to use the DevOps REST API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/get%20feeds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

There does not appear to be a package that interfaces to this API that I could see so I created a very simple library that uses a few of the REST API methods

https://github.com/conficient/DevOpsNugetClient

I used this to successfully query and delete several hundred redundant packages and related versions on our internal feed.